# extracting rectangle from binary image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to crop a image using OpenCV and python. I am following a tutorial "https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-box-detection-algorithm-for-any-image-containing-boxes-756c15d7ed26"

my code so far:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

os.chdir("D:\\RTK\\")


# Read the image
img = cv2.imread('try.jpg', 0)
img1 = cv2.imread('try.jpg')


# Thresholding the image
(thresh, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Invert the image
img_bin = 255-img_bin 
#cv2.imwrite("Image_bin.jpg",img_bin)

# Defining a kernel length
kernel_length = np.array(img).shape[1]//80

# A verticle kernel of (1 X kernel_length), which will detect all the verticle lines from the image.
verticle_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_length))

# A horizontal kernel of (kernel_length X 1), which will help to detect all the horizontal line from the image.
hori_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))

# A kernel of (3 X 3) ones.
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

img_ttt = cv2.dilate(img_bin, kernel, iterations =1)

#cv2.imwrite("Image_bin_dil.jpg",img_ttt)



# Morphological operation to detect vertical lines from an image
img_temp1 = cv2.erode(img_ttt, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
verticle_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp1, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imwrite("verticle_lines.jpg",verticle_lines_img)

#minLineLength = 100
#maxLineGap = 10
#lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(verticle_lines_img,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
#
#for line in lines:
#    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
#        cv2.line(verticle_lines_img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,0),1)
#
#cv2.imwrite('Written_Back_Results.jpg',verticle_lines_img)
# Morphological operation to detect horizontal lines from an image
img_temp2 = cv2.erode(img_ttt, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
horizontal_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp2, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
#cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines.jpg",horizontal_lines_img)

# Weighting parameters, this will decide the quantity of an image to be added to make a new image.
alpha = 0.5
beta = 1.0 - alpha

# This function helps to add two image with specific weight parameter to get a third image as summation of two image.
img_final_bin = cv2.addWeighted(verticle_lines_img, alpha, horizontal_lines_img, beta, 0.0)
img_final_bin = cv2.erode(~img_final_bin, kernel, iterations=2)
(thresh, img_final_bin) = cv2.threshold(img_final_bin, 128,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("img_final_bin.jpg",img_final_bin)


# Find contours for image, which will detect all the boxes
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_final_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)





def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0

    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True

    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1

    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
        key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)



# Sort all the contours by top to bottom.
(contours, boundingBoxes) = sort_contours(contours, method="left-to-right")



idx = 0

for c in contours:

    # Returns the location and width,height for every contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    idx += 1
    new_img = img1[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    per_h = (new_img.shape[0]/img1.shape[0])*100.0
    per_w = (new_img.shape[1]/img1.shape[1])*100.0

    if (per_h > 80 and per_w > 80) and (per_h < 100 and per_w < 100):
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.jpg', new_img)
```

Now I want to extract the rectangle marked in red color, but problem is that

```
cv2.findContours is not finding the rectangle marked in red color.
```

Kindly help me to extract rectangle in marked red color in image 1 from the Image 2.

```
IMAGE 1
```

[image]

```
IMAGE 2
```

[image]

Comment: Wowsers, that red rectangle is difficult to see! There might be an easier way to do it. Are those your images? Is the rectangle that you need extracted always going to be red on a black and white image? Is there any reason you can't just detect the red pixels and define a bounding rectangle using the min/max x/y co-ordinates?

Comment: @Pam From what I understood, the OP actually wants to detect the black rectangle in image 2 which has been labeled with red in image 1. If this is the case, a more specific problem definition is needed. For instance, there are clearly many other rectangles in the image, so how is the labeled rectangle different from the others?

Comment: @Ali250 you understood correctly. Image is binary (image 2) and my problem is that I am not able to label the rectangle marked with red colour. I marked it manually for the explanation. I am thinking to extract vertical lines first using Hough transformation  and loop over the lines and then assign first two lines and last two limes

Comment: I am thinking to extract vertical lines first and then using Hough transformation vertical lines will be extracted and then I will loop over lines and assign black color to first two vertical lines and last two vertical lines. After that as mentioned in tutorial images with vertical and horizontal lines will be merged and I may be able to get desired rectangle.